# SAP UI5 XML View Column Name

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to build a Table in SAP UI5.
I have an Odata-Service, which has the two EntitySets ColumnSet and DataSet.

In my ColumnSet there are multiple Entities with some parameters like id, id-num and so on.

Now I want to bind the name-attribute from the entities to the Column-Names shown in the UI.

Im using a XML View.

An entity will look like this:

[image]

And for the talbe:

[image]

So at the Position, where now "Name1" stands,  I want to show the 
"Id" of ColumnSet(0), which would be "USER".

But I dont know how to bind this properly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the text element inside the [column element](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Column).

Example:

```
<Column>
<Text text=“{/USER}“>
</Column>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly this doesn't work, "USER" would be the output of my firsts entity "Id" and if I bind <Text text="{/Id}"/> I dont get any result

Comment: Then you probably didn’t bind your table items correctly. Your items should be {YourOdataModel>ColumnSet} and then {USER} instead of {/USER}